# Android connectedCheck task fails when run with the build task but not when run alone

Tags: android, gradle

```
$ ./gradlew clean build connectedCheck
```

yields

```
Unable to find instrumentation target package: my.package

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > hasTests FAILED
No tests found.
:app:connectedAndroidTest FAILED
```

while

```
$ ./gradlew clean check connectedCheck
```

results in

```
...
:app:connectedAndroidTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The only thing unique about my setup is that I have a pure java module that utilizes the `'java'` Gradle plugin next to an android app using the android build tools Gradle plugin:

```
project
- core (pure java)
- app (com.android.application)
```

and the app project has a compile time dependency on the artifacts of the core project:

```
# app/build.gradle
depenedencies { 
    compile project(':core') 
}
```

I'm using build tools **21.1.2** and sdk tools **24.0.2**.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention I do one more less-than-ordinary step which is renaming the output file for the apk:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def apkVariant = variant.outputs[0]
    def outputFile = apkVariant.outputFile
    def versionName = android.defaultConfig.versionName
    def newName = outputFile.getName().replace(".apk", "-${versionName}.apk")
    apkVariant.outputFile = file("${outputFile.parentFile}/newName")
}
```

***Removing this code solves the issue.*** But, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the rename logic.

```
def newName = outputFile.getName().replace(".apk", "-${versionName}.apk")
apkVariant.outputFile = file("${outputFile.parentFile}/newName")
```

I forgot the `'$'`. It should be:

```
apkVariant.outputFile = file("${outputFile.parentFile}/$newName")
```

Because of the typo, all the app variants were sharing the same output file and my test apk was getting overwritten by whatever variant came next in the build.